# Doctrine2 count result returns wrong number

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

$tickets = $qb->select('COUNT(ticket.id)')->from('MyBundle:Ticket', 'ticket');
var_dump($tickets->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult());
```

returns

```
array(1) {
  [0]=&gt;
  array(1) {
    [1]=&gt;
    string(3) "125"
  }
}
```

But in database there are just 5 entries. Any ideas what is wrong?

```
var_dump($tickets->getQuery()->getSql());
```

gives

> SELECT COUNT(t0_.id) AS sclr0 FROM ticket t1_, ticket t2_, ticket t0_
>   GROUP BY t0_.id ORDER BY t2_.created_at ASC LIMIT 1

Comment: Post this as answer please with code example

Comment: I misunderstood your question, can you post the result of `$tickets->getQuery()->getSQL();`

Comment: what does `$tickets = $qb->select('ticket.id')->from('MyBundle:Ticket', 'ticket'); var_dump($tickets->getQuery()->getScalarResult());`  return?

Comment: array(1) {
  [0]=&gt;
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(2) "12"
  }
}

Comment: Returns correct number for me. Is that the full code? It's not clear where ORDER BY clause comes from.

Comment: There is something weird in the generated SQL, the `FROM` clause is doing an implicit `JOIN` three times on the same table. 5 * 5 * 5 which gives a correct result of 125. Do you have some self-referenced relations in your ticket entity?

Comment: @BorisGuéry all relations in doctrine2 are lazy loaded afaik. It won't load them until you ask to

Comment: @meze indeed, but he may have changed this behavior. It is just to be sure. However, the problem has something to do with the way Doctrine2 constructs the `FROM` clauses. It shouldn't be doing such implicit `JOIN`.

Comment: As @meze, tried your code and it gives the right count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually before this query there were two more queries using the same query builder instance. This might be the problem. I remove the queries and now the count query works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can try as:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$query = "SELECT count(s) FROM MyBundle:Ticket s ";
$queryObj = $em->createQuery($query);
$result = $queryObj->execute();
```

I didn't test this code. But It should work.